# Why is a class with multiple public access specifiers standard_layout?

Tags: c++, standard-layout

I was just playing around with g++, and I found that

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {
public: int x;
public: char y;
public: double z;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<Foo>::value, "Foo is not standard layout");

int main() {}
```

Compiles just fine.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11364029/956134) answer, `data members across access specifiers may be reordered in memory`. So there's no gaurantee that `x` has to actually be the first member of `Foo` when actually laid out in memory. The way I've defined `Foo`, `y` could actually be the first element right?

I thought standard layout meant that you could more or less understand how the bytes are laid out for the given type. Allowing fields in a standard layout type to be reordered in an arbitrary manner seems counterintuitive to me. Why is this allowed?

Comment: `Foo` may not be standard layout doesn't means `Foo` _must not_ be standard layout. i.e. different version of the compiler may choose to fail on the static assert. But if it compiles, you know it must be standard layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All members of your structure have the same access specifier: `public`. The fact that the keyword appears before every class member is immaterial. This is equivalent to the `public` access specifier appearing once, before all class members.

Comment: So is the answer I linked incorrect? Because that answer suggests that having a `public` access specifier appearing more than once does have some semantic difference

Comment: By "answer I linked" I mean this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362543/using-same-c-access-specifiers-mulitple-times/11364029#11364029

Comment: @math4tots It looks to me like the answer is wrong.  from draft n3797 9.2 p13: *Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object*  So even though private, protected and public have no order to each other all objects of one type have and absolute order to each other.

Comment: Ah, that's embarrassing ^_^; I told someone at work today that they were different... I'll learn to refer to the standard before pretending I know things next time

Comment: That quote from the standard mentions ordering, but doesn't mention whether those fields must be contiguous (e.g. a private field could still potentially be inserted between two public fields), do you happen to know if there's any language about when that can and can't happen?

Comment: I searched http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf for the term "contiguous" and couldn't find anything, but I thought maybe they used different terminology to express the idea of "two fields being next to each other with nothing between them"